# Swagger2 can't access

Tags: java, swagger-2.0

I am using Swagger+Springboot, dependency

[image]

swaggerConfiguration also add, but when I visit swagger-ui.html, then is nothing, console print

[image]

Who can help me to fix it

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You could and should post your code snippets and console output with code markup in this question. It will save anyone reviewing it to open 3 separate links and, in its current state, if anything should ever happen to those imgur links, your question will become meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your post with your config code?

It should look something like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.abc.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: hello,It seems that swagger cannot be used due to the introduction of spring cloud config.Then i separate springcloud config server to a independent module,everything is ok。